# My <body> isn't accepting background color/image

Tags: css, html, header

CSS code

```
body { 
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: #ececec;
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;

}
```

Link: http://grupocoral.netai.net/

No matter what I do I can't change background properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `<style type="text/css">` and  `</style>` from your css file.

Comment: @langel The browser could not parse your CSS properly, that's why your styles were not applied correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have placed your CSS code in the style sheet along with the `<style>` tags. You shouldn't do that when attaching an external CSS stylesheet. You can directly define the styles.

Remove

`<style type="text/css">` & `</style>` from your file `style.css`

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS document `style.css` the opening lines are the following:

```
/* CSS Document */
<style type="text/css">
body {
```

You need to delete `<style type="text/css">` from `style.css` because that is only used when writing styles inside the `<style>` tag in an HTML document.  Also delete `</style>` at the foot of the document.  Your `style.css` document is a CSS document, not an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Because your stylesheet has html style-tags in it.

remove `<style type="text/css">` from the top and `</style>` from the bottom

Answer (score -2):

background:#ececec url('/path/image');

also see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and does not help towards a solution. And I'm not talking about the link.